# Different usage of "word" and "words" in a particular sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I understand that "words" is plural form of "word".

So can we say:

> Ram was true to his words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage does not refer to the words specifically, but the confidence behind them. As a concept, you would not pluralize it. See [***word***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/word):

> 3) a promise, affirmation, or assurance "   *⇒ to give a person one's word*"

So:

> Ram was true to his **word**.